# Word types + に/を + する

Tags: grammar, particle-に, adjectives, nouns

There have been a few times where I have come across `にする` and `をする` and I am asking about different situations of when it is used and its meaning.

The first example is `Adjective (specifically な) + にする`:

> 私は出来るだけ静かにしていた。 I kept as quiet as possible.

1. Does `静かにして` more literally mean "made quiet", how does it differ from `になる`?
2. Does this syntax of `にする` work the same for i-adjectives (`面白いにする`)?

I've also been noticing more and more the grammar of `Noun + を/に する`

1. What is the difference between using `を` and `に`?
2. Is this grammar point used only because the noun isn't a suru-verb, for example does `勉強に/をする` not work?

My question has kind of just been dumped onto you but I feel like in order for me to understand this grammar I need understand these things that have confused me the most.

Comment: Yes, 静かにする is to make something quiet. In this context, "made myself" quiet. 静かになる is to *become* quiet. In general _にする is someone making something the case, _になる is to become the case. Meanwhile, をする is a pretty different thing meaning to "do" something, and isn't particularly related to にする beyond using the same verb.

Comment: ^@Cowan, `静かにする is to make something quiet.` Naw.. する can also be an intransitive verb, you know. こうする、仲良くする、おとなしくする、いい子にする、じっとする、静かにする... [明鏡国語辞典 「する」自動詞 ❻ 《様態を表す形容詞・形容動詞の連用形、「こう」「そう」など、副詞句に直接付いて》 **そのような行動や態度をとる。** 「静かにしろ」
「人に優しくする」
「彼女とは常日ごろ親しくしている」
「言われたとおりにする」
「こうすればいいでしょう」](https://sakura-paris.org/dict/%E6%98%8E%E9%8F%A1%E5%9B%BD%E8%AA%9E%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8/exact/%E7%82%BA%E3%82%8B)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 私は出来るだけ静かに**して**いた。 I kept as quiet as possible.

The する, used with the continuative form (連用形) of an i-adjective or na-adjective, or an adverbial phrase such as こう、そう etc., is an intransitive verb meaning そのような行動や態度をとる ("to behave/act in a particular way").

明鏡国語辞典 states:

> する 〘自動詞〙
> ❻《様態を表す形容詞・形容動詞の連用形、「こう」「そう」など、副詞句に直接付いて》 そのような行動や態度をとる。「静かに**しろ**」「人に優しく**する**」「彼女とは常日ごろ親しく**して**いる」「言われたとおりに**する**」「こう**すれ**ばいいでしょう」

---

> 1. Does 静かにして more literally mean "made quiet", how does it differ from になる?

No, 静かにする literally means "to behave/act quiet" → "to keep quiet".
「神妙にする」 "to be docile"
「勝手にする」「好きにする」 "to act as one pleases"
静かになる means "to become quiet (after not being quiet)". It involves a change of state or transition from being not quiet to being quiet.

> 2. Does this syntax of にする work the same for i-adjectives (面白いにする)?

You can use this する with i-adjectives, but not 面白いに. The continuative form of i-adjectives ends with ～く. eg:
優しい → 優しく 「人に優しくする」 "to be kind to others"
おとなしい → おとなしく 「おとなしくする」 "to stay quiet"
よい → よく 「友達と仲よくする」 "to get along with friends"

> 1. What is the difference between using を and に?

(I don't really know what you're asking but) ～をする can mean many different things. Used with an を, the する is transitive. eg:
勉強をする to **do** studying → study
教師をする to **work as/play the role of** a teacher
ネクタイをする to **wear** a tie
etc...

And ～を‥にする means "make/turn ～ (into)‥" or "choose ～ as ‥". eg:
牛乳をチーズにする "make milk into cheese"
部屋をきれいにする "make a room clean"
山田さんを議長にする "make Yamada-san a chairperson / elect Yamada-san chairperson"
ワインをお土産にする "choose wine as a gift"
etc...

> 2. Is this grammar point used only because the noun isn't a suru-verb, for example does 勉強に/をする not work?

Well, it's because the する has a different meaning.
You can say "Noun+に+する" using this する, though it doesn't seem productive, since this is the only example that I can think of:
いい子にする *lit.* "to behave/act a good child" → "to be a good boy/girl".

勉強にする doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Adjectives are words that modify nouns, whereas adverbs are words that modify adjectives and verbs.

By adding に to a na-adjective, you turn it into an adverb. In this way, 静かにする can be seen as the adverb "quietly" directly modifying the verb する "to do":

> 静かにする。Literally "to do quietly", i.e. "to be quiet".

I think that this sense of "to be quiet" fits nicely in your example sentence. Also note that 静かにする is a very common sentence so it can be thought of as a set phrase.

However, note that you could use 静かに as an adverb to modify other verbs, too:

> 静かに寝ている。Sleeping peacefully/quietly

On the other hand, to turn an i-adjective into an adverb, you cannot attach に. Instead, drop the い and replace it by a く. For example:

速い fast (adjective) → 速く fast (adverb), rapidly

> あの車は速く走ります。That car runs fast.

Comment: Any hint from the downvoter as for why this answer is not right? I'll try to improve it. Thank you!

Comment: @Chocolate ↑↑ ?

Comment: およ？　私、ダウンボードしてないよ。

Comment: あらっ、もしかしたらChocolateさんが私のAnswerを見て何か正しくないことを見つけたので自分のAnswerを投稿しようと思った。すみません

Comment: Apologies – the downvoter was seemingly me; I had meant to upvote your answer but must have had fat fingers...! So... I made a small edit to your post and have upvoted you now!

Comment: @henreetee Ah I see, it makes sense now. Thank you!